# Drove my chevy to the levy and the levy was dry

Tags: meaning

Years ago I had this English teacher (from UK) who asked us to translate American Pie to Swedish. A quite difficult task of course :). Anyhow, he told us that "Drove my Chevy to the levy but the levy was dry" meant I drove my Chevrolet to the movie theatre but the film was dull.
Anyone else who has heard this?

Comment: Nope, never heard that interpretation. Not sure where it would stem from, either. The words are actually “Drove my Chevy to the ***levee***, but the ***levee*** was dry”. A levee is kind of a dike, except along a river instead of the sea, so it’s a place you’d normally expect to be wet. If you find the levee dry, that usually means the river has run dry as well, which fits rather nicely with the rest of the lyrics: the whole song gives off a kind of ‘ghost-town’ feeling of things lost.

Comment: Janus has it right.  I think your teacher was completely off base on that one.

Comment: *"Drove my Chevy to the levee, but the levee was dry"* could be symbolic; it's similar to the lines *"I went down to the sacred store. Where I'd heard the music years before. But the man there said the music wouldn't play."* But the entire song is about music/rock and roll, and not films.

Comment: @user662852 - When you say "contemporary", I presume you're thinking of the Led Zeppelin song "When The Levee Breaks" (and, I presume, you mean "contemporary to Don McLean".) But that song was a reworking/homage/ripoff (depending whom you listen to) of [a song first recorded in 1929](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_the_Levee_Breaks), in reference to [a flood that happened in 1927](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Mississippi_Flood_of_1927).

Comment: The center of the song is the Day The Music Died: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_the_Music_Died

Comment: I didn't find anything that sheds much light on the actual meaning of the phrase, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Pie_%28song%29#Interpretations says that Don McLean was going to / did finally reveal the meaning of the lyrics when the original manuscript went for auction in April 2015.  McLean: "Basically in American Pie things are heading in the wrong direction. ... It [life] is becoming less idyllic. I don't know whether you consider that wrong or right but it is a morality song in a sense."  http://www.don-mclean.com/?p=261

Comment: Your English teacher knows how to pick'em then.  Don McLean lyrics to American Pie are almost as difficult to interpret as Shakespeare.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for an interpretation of song lyrics.

Comment: Wow, you really stepped in it here.  You should be aware that no one has ever been able to agree on the meaning of the lyrics to *American Pie*, most likely because they're literally a bunch of meaningless word salad.  When someone asked Don McLean in an interview what the lyrics mean, he answered surprisingly candidly that they mean "I'll never have to work again."

Comment: I always thought it had to do with booze. The following lyric is about whisky and rye, so it makes some sense.

Answer (score 44):

It's "levee."  Levy is somebody else.  "American Pie" is Don McLean's song about the change from the (supposedly) golden era of 1950s America through the turbulent 1960s as reflected in pop music.  A levee is a quay or a dike along a river to control flooding, in any case, a place where you'd expect to find water.  But in the song, the water is missing.  This is likely an allusion to the 1950s variety show featuring music of those years and hosted by singer Dinah Shore.  During the program, she sang a song to accompany a Chevrolet car commercial.  The song rhymed "Chevy" with "levee."  To take a look and a listen click [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qhR8GZ_WWMM).  In the song, those times symbolized by Dinah Shore and the contemporary music are gone like the missing water that's left the levee dry.

Comment: Oh man, the memories. In Vietnam, the troops would sing, "See the DMZ, from your APC, America is sending you to Nam."

Comment: Considering the black roots of American music, the song's nostalgia for the 1950s is quite ironic as that era was the beginning of the last stand of American apartheid.  The Little Rock crisis happened smack in the middle of the run of the Dinah Shore Show.

Comment: Nostalgia is strongest for things that didn't really exist.

Comment: I thought it was more specifically about the plane crash that killed Buddy Holly, Richie Valens, and the Big Bopper.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman The three stages of human understanding: 1. Not realizing it's really about Buddy Holly. 2. Realizing it's really about Buddy Holly. 3. Realizing it's not really about Buddy Holly.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Apparently McLean has said that the song was inspired by the plane crash, and the lyric "the day the music died" lends credence to that, but he's always been cagey about the meaning of the song's references.  He usually responds to the question with "It means I never have to work again if I don't want to."  This year McLean sold the original manuscript of the lyrics for $1.2M while he whined about the gloomy state of the world, no better than when he wrote AP.  Nothing sadder than an old rocker.  Unless it's an old white American rocker pining for the 1950s.

Comment: For another use of the word "levee" in a song consider "When The Levee Breaks" (originally by [Kansas Joe McCoy and his wife Memphis Minnie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=swhEa8vuP6U), but made most familiar to modern audiences by [Led Zeppelin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbrjRKB586s)). The song refers to [The Great Mississippi Flood of 1927](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Mississippi_Flood_of_1927), where levee failures resulted in the flooding of vast areas of the Mississippi valley.

Answer (score 19):

Speaking as an American who is roughly contemporaneous with Don McLean, I'm afraid you were the victim of a British teacher who had no concept of 1950's US culture. Except, perhaps, what he'd read in the magazines.

The first verses of "American Pie", that is, the verses preceding the second chorus, place the singer as a high-school student in the US south. (This despite the fact that McLean himself went to prep school in New York.) He has a paper route, he drives a pickup, he goes to dances in the high school gym. He knows a bunch of "good ole boys" and drives to a levee. As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levee) points out, US use of "levee" is pretty much restricted to the Midwest and Deep South, and "good ole boys" refines the location. It's not actually clear what "the levee was dry" means, but part of American Pie's charm is its ability to mash up phrases and keep going. An entirely reasonable interpretation (hampered by the fact that McLean grew up entirely in the Northeast) is that the local teenagers would get together out on some levee to party and get drunk, although that's such universal behavior that McLean should have had no trouble visualizing it.

The next "ten years", of course, were the '60s, and the less said about that the better.

Finally, I draw a complete blank on any connection between "levy" and movie theaters. An uncharitable suspicion is that your teacher confused "levy" with "marquee".

Comment: I disagree that "**US use of "levee" is pretty much restricted to the Midwest and Deep South.** *Where do you get that?* You link to Wikipedia, but I see nothing on that page that supports this claim. That page makes clear that *levee* is used for both rivers and low-lying coastal areas. And it even shows two (!) pictures of levees (labeled as such!) near Sacramento, California. Restricted to the Midwest and Deep South? No sir. (The rest of your answer is OK.)

Comment: I've never quite cracked the lyrics to this song.  "The levee was dry" might be taken to mean that no one has any booze there, but in the next breath we hear "them good ol' boys were drinking whiskey and rye".  As to a levee being dry of water, that would be the normal case, so there's no reason for the "but".  (There's probably a web site somewhere dedicated to analyzing this song.)

Comment: @HotLicks - "a" web site?

Comment: There is definitely at least one serious analysis on line; found it some years ago GIYF/GIFY.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - Where I live we pronounce the "w" in "web".

Comment: @HotLicks i believe the point is there will be far more than just one web site on the topic

Comment: @KateGregory - Oh yesss.

Comment: (Southerner here) I concur that the song has a "southern" way of phrasing the lyrics.

Comment: FWIW, I blame this on the teacher rather than the teacher's nationality, because as a Brit myself the quote seems quite clear to me!!

Comment: For reasons no one really understands, people like to hang out near a body of water, especially one that's moving in some way.  It's just fun.  People don't like hanging out near a muddy rut where water used to be nearly as much.  It's just depressing.  Thus, the narrator drove his pickup to the water to hang out with his buddies, and have innocent good times like he used to do.  But when he got there there was no water, and all his friends had switched to hard liquor.  It just sucked.  Which reminded him of America after Vietnam in a lot of ways.

Comment: Another thing which might be misunderstood is the "good old boys" line. In southern vernacular, this does NOT imply that those people are his friends, or known to him, or good in any way. A "good ol' boy" is slang for a traditional, conservative, rural person. Example: "I made a joke about the president last night and got beat up by some good ol' boys!"

Answer (score 2):

Other than the correction of the word "levee" (not 'levy', like taxes), everyone's interpretation of the song is just that, **their** interpretation of the song.

Don McLean has **never** given an interpretation of the whole song - just allusions to the general meaning. Here's one place recently:
http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/04/08/don-mclean-american-pie_n_7024486.html

Answer (score 1):

I attended a fabulous outdoor concert near Boston many years ago. Don McLean appeared along with many other artists. He told his audience that many people ask him about the meaning of his best-known song. He said, "It means I don't have to work very hard any more."